# Declaring variables from object property

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple object with constants.

```
{
  KEY1: "value1",
  KEY2: "value2"
}
```

I want to make them accessible globally.

I make this object globally, use it like `Config.KEY1`
But I am trying to find a way so that I only use `KEY` to get the value.
*app.js*

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

//load app config variables
const config = require('config') //this returns the plain object with config keys and dvalues
...config //oops, can't do this :(
```

If I could do somthing like below, I think it should work.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

//load app config variables
const KEY1 = "value1"
const KEY2 = "value2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destructure the config object when you import it, so that you have standalone variable names:

```
const { KEY1, KEY2 } = require('config');
```

You can also combine the config with the global object, allowing you to use those standalone variable names anywhere without importing the config everywhere, but it's not such a good idea IMO:

```
const util = require('./util');
Object.assign(global, util);
```

(make sure you don't have any properties that conflict with properties on the global object)

Comment: I am already using it, thanks though.  I use this syntax in every module where the constant is needed, that's also a good way. But I am trying to find a way to separate it from app.js and load all the configs globally?

Comment: You can put the properties on the global object so you don't have to import it to use the standalone variable names, but it's not a great idea I think - more chances of name collisions, less obvious module dependency chains